# Automatically Upload The File After Saving

Tags: textmate, sftp, rackspace, rackspace-cloud

I have a Rackspace Cloud Server, where I host my site, the problem is that I need to upload the code every time using a SFTP program, but isn't any way to automate this?

*PS: I use TextMate*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you also use Transmit, you can enable Docksend for a project and map this command to a key of your choice in the bundle editor:

```
#!/bin/sh
osascript "${TM_BUNDLE_SUPPORT}/bin/send_to_transmit.applescript" "$TM_FILEPATH" &>/dev/console &
echo "Sent ‘${TM_FILENAME}’ to Transmit"
```

Edit: There is actually a bundle that takes care of that here http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Bundles/Transmit.tmbundle/

I use CTRL+Shift+F for that.